# how to script windows access to a pwd protected SMB solaris share

Tags: samba, scripting

I need to create shortcuts on a WindowsXP box to about 100 solaris directories which are mounted as SMB shares. If I go through the process manually, I create a shortcut, entering the UNC path as the target.  When I click on the shortcut, Windows asks me for a username/password.  Once I enter that and click "Remember", then the shortcut is accessible without problems.

How can I automate this process in a script so I can do this to multiple PCs.  I know how to write a powershell script to create the shortcut, but not sure how to do the password entering, remembering part.

Comment: windows shouldn't be asking for credentials to a share that the user has access to with his current credentials.  If you use groups to assign permissions and put the users in the groups you shouldn't need to save passwords

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\BMDan>net use /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

Comment: +!, `net use \\computername\sharename password /user:username /savecred`